# Convert count to percentages

Tags: r, ggplot2, percentage

I'm trying to make a ggplot that shows the percentage of people who reported a specific activity happening at a certain time during the day. One think I could not figure out how can I convert count to percentages - to say that 70% of people reported sleeping activity at 5am. So, i would like to have percentages on the y axis. Below the plot that I made

[image]

My data:

```
structure(list(time = c("04:00", "04:10", "04:20", "04:30", "04:40", 
"04:50", "05:00", "05:10", "05:20", "05:30", "05:40", "05:50", 
"06:00", "06:10", "06:20", "06:30", "06:40", "06:50", "07:00", 
"07:10", "07:20", "07:30", "07:40", "07:50", "08:00", "08:10", 
"08:20", "08:30", "08:40", "08:50", "09:00", "09:10", "09:20", 
"09:30", "09:40", "09:50", "10:00", "10:10", "10:20", "10:30", 
"10:40", "10:50", "11:00", "11:10", "11:20", "11:30", "11:40", 
"11:50", "12:00", "12:10", "12:20", "12:30", "12:40", "12:50", 
"13:00", "13:10", "13:20", "13:30", "13:40", "13:50", "14:00", 
"14:10", "14:20", "14:30", "14:40", "14:50", "15:00", "15:10", 
"15:20", "15:30", "15:40", "15:50", "16:00", "16:10", "16:20", 
"16:30", "16:40", "16:50", "17:00", "17:10", "17:20", "17:30", 
"17:40", "17:50", "18:00", "18:10", "18:20", "18:30", "18:40", 
"18:50", "19:00", "19:10", "19:20", "19:30", "19:40", "19:50", 
"20:00", "20:10", "20:20", "20:30", "20:40", "20:50", "21:00", 
"21:10", "21:20", "21:30", "21:40", "21:50", "22:00", "22:10", 
"22:20", "22:30", "22:40", "22:50", "23:00", "23:10", "23:20", 
"23:30", "23:40", "23:50", "00:00", "00:10", "00:20", "00:30", 
"00:40", "00:50", "01:00", "01:10", "01:20", "01:30", "01:40", 
"01:50", "02:00", "02:10", "02:20", "02:30", "02:40", "02:50", 
"03:00", "03:10", "03:20", "03:30", "03:40", "03:50", "04:00", 
"04:10", "04:20", "04:30", "04:40", "04:50", "05:00", "05:10", 
"05:20", "05:30", "05:40", "05:50", "06:00", "06:10", "06:20", 
"06:30", "06:40", "06:50", "07:00", "07:10", "07:20", "07:30", 
"07:40", "07:50", "08:00", "08:10", "08:20", "08:30", "08:40", 
"08:50", "09:00", "09:10", "09:20", "09:30", "09:40", "09:50", 
"10:00", "10:10", "10:20", "10:30", "10:40", "10:50", "11:00", 
"11:10", "11:20", "11:30", "11:40", "11:50", "12:00", "12:10", 
"12:20", "12:30", "12:40", "12:50", "13:00", "13:10", "13:20", 
"13:30", "13:40", "13:50", "14:00", "14:10", "14:20", "14:30", 
"14:40", "14:50", "15:00", "15:10", "15:20", "15:30", "15:40", 
"15:50", "16:00", "16:10", "16:20", "16:30", "16:40", "16:50", 
"17:00", "17:10", "17:20", "17:30", "17:40", "17:50", "18:00", 
"18:10", "18:20", "18:30", "18:40", "18:50", "19:00", "19:10", 
"19:20", "19:30", "19:40", "19:50", "20:00", "20:10", "20:20", 
"20:30", "20:40", "20:50", "21:00", "21:10", "21:20", "21:30", 
"21:40", "21:50", "22:00", "22:10", "22:20", "22:30", "22:40", 
"22:50", "23:00", "23:10", "23:20", "23:30", "23:40", "23:50", 
"00:00", "00:10", "00:20", "00:30", "00:40", "00:50", "01:00", 
"01:10", "01:20", "01:30", "01:40", "01:50", "02:00", "02:10", 
"02:20", "02:30", "02:40", "02:50", "03:00", "03:10", "03:20", 
"03:30", "03:40", "03:50", "04:00", "04:10", "04:20", "04:30", 
"04:40", "04:50", "05:00", "05:10", "05:20", "05:30", "05:40", 
"05:50", "06:00", "06:10", "06:20", "06:30", "06:40", "06:50", 
"07:00", "07:10", "07:20", "07:30", "07:40", "07:50", "08:00", 
"08:10", "08:20", "08:30", "08:40", "08:50", "09:00", "09:10", 
"09:20", "09:30", "09:40", "09:50", "10:00", "10:10", "10:20", 
"10:30", "10:40", "10:50", "11:00", "11:10", "11:20", "11:30", 
"11:40", "11:50", "12:00", "12:10", "12:20", "12:30", "12:40", 
"12:50", "13:00", "13:10", "13:20", "13:30", "13:40", "13:50", 
"14:00", "14:10", "14:20", "14:30", "14:40", "14:50", "15:00", 
"15:10", "15:20", "15:30", "15:40", "15:50", "16:00", "16:10", 
"16:20", "16:30", "16:40", "16:50", "17:00", "17:10", "17:20", 
"17:30", "17:40", "17:50", "18:00", "18:10", "18:20", "18:30", 
"18:40", "18:50", "19:00", "19:10", "19:20", "19:30", "19:40", 
"19:50", "20:00", "20:10", "20:20", "20:30", "20:40", "20:50", 
"21:00", "21:10", "21:20", "21:30", "21:40", "21:50", "22:00", 
"22:10", "22:20", "22:30", "22:40", "22:50", "23:00", "23:10", 
"23:20", "23:30", "23:40", "23:50", "00:00", "00:10", "00:20", 
"00:30", "00:40", "00:50", "01:00", "01:10", "01:20", "01:30", 
"01:40", "01:50", "02:00", "02:10", "02:20", "02:30", "02:40", 
"02:50", "03:00", "03:10", "03:20", "03:30", "03:40", "03:50", 
"04:00", "04:10", "04:20", "04:30", "04:40", "04:50", "05:00", 
"05:10", "05:20", "05:30", "05:40", "05:50", "06:00", "06:10", 
"06:20", "06:30", "06:40", "06:50", "07:00", "07:10", "07:20", 
"07:30", "07:40", "07:50", "08:00", "08:10", "08:20", "08:30", 
"08:40", "08:50", "09:00", "09:10", "09:20", "09:30", "09:40", 
"09:50", "10:00", "10:10", "10:20", "10:30", "10:40", "10:50", 
"11:00", "11:10", "11:20", "11:30", "11:40", "11:50", "12:00", 
"12:10", "12:20", "12:30", "12:40", "12:50", "13:00", "13:10", 
"13:20", "13:30", "13:40", "13:50", "14:00", "14:10", "14:20", 
"14:30", "14:40", "14:50", "15:00", "15:10", "15:20", "15:30", 
"15:40", "15:50", "16:00", "16:10", "16:20", "16:30", "16:40", 
"16:50", "17:00", "17:10", "17:20", "17:30", "17:40", "17:50", 
"18:00", "18:10", "18:20", "18:30", "18:40", "18:50", "19:00", 
"19:10", "19:20", "19:30", "19:40", "19:50", "20:00", "20:10", 
"20:20", "20:30", "20:40", "20:50", "21:00", "21:10", "21:20", 
"21:30", "21:40", "21:50", "22:00", "22:10", "22:20", "22:30", 
"22:40", "22:50", "23:00", "23:10", "23:20", "23:30", "23:40", 
"23:50", "00:00", "00:10", "00:20", "00:30", "00:40", "00:50", 
"01:00", "01:10", "01:20", "01:30", "01:40", "01:50", "02:00", 
"02:10", "02:20", "02:30", "02:40", "02:50", "03:00", "03:10", 
"03:20", "03:30", "03:40", "03:50", "04:00", "04:10", "04:20", 
"04:30", "04:40", "04:50", "05:00", "05:10", "05:20", "05:30", 
"05:40", "05:50", "06:00", "06:10", "06:20", "06:30", "06:40", 
"06:50", "07:00", "07:10", "07:20", "07:30", "07:40", "07:50", 
"08:00", "08:10", "08:20", "08:30", "08:40", "08:50", "09:00", 
"09:10", "09:20", "09:30", "09:40", "09:50", "10:00", "10:10", 
"10:20", "10:30", "10:40", "10:50", "11:00", "11:10", "11:20", 
"11:30", "11:40", "11:50", "12:00", "12:10", "12:20", "12:30", 
"12:40", "12:50", "13:00", "13:10", "13:20", "13:30", "13:40", 
"13:50", "14:00", "14:10", "14:20", "14:30", "14:40", "14:50", 
"15:00", "15:10", "15:20", "15:30", "15:40", "15:50", "16:00", 
"16:10", "16:20", "16:30", "16:40", "16:50", "17:00", "17:10", 
"17:20", "17:30", "17:40", "17:50", "18:00", "18:10", "18:20", 
"18:30", "18:40", "18:50", "19:00", "19:10", "19:20", "19:30", 
"19:40", "19:50", "20:00", "20:10", "20:20", "20:30", "20:40", 
"20:50", "21:00", "21:10", "21:20", "21:30", "21:40", "21:50", 
"22:00", "22:10", "22:20", "22:30", "22:40", "22:50", "23:00", 
"23:10", "23:20", "23:30", "23:40", "23:50", "00:00", "00:10", 
"00:20", "00:30", "00:40", "00:50", "01:00", "01:10", "01:20", 
"01:30", "01:40", "01:50", "02:00", "02:10", "02:20", "02:30", 
"02:40", "02:50", "03:00", "03:10", "03:20", "03:30", "03:40", 
"03:50", "04:00", "04:10", "04:20", "04:30", "04:40", "04:50", 
"05:00", "05:10", "05:20", "05:30", "05:40", "05:50", "06:00", 
"06:10", "06:20", "06:30", "06:40", "06:50", "07:00", "07:10", 
"07:20", "07:30", "07:40", "07:50", "08:00", "08:10", "08:20", 
"08:30", "08:40", "08:50", "09:00", "09:10", "09:20", "09:30", 
"09:40", "09:50", "10:00", "10:10", "10:20", "10:30", "10:40", 
"10:50", "11:00", "11:10", "11:20", "11:30", "11:40", "11:50", 
"12:00", "12:10", "12:20", "12:30", "12:40", "12:50", "13:00", 
"13:10", "13:20", "13:30", "13:40", "13:50", "14:00", "14:10", 
"14:20", "14:30", "14:40", "14:50", "15:00", "15:10", "15:20", 
"15:30", "15:40", "15:50", "16:00", "16:10", "16:20", "16:30", 
"16:40", "16:50", "17:00", "17:10", "17:20", "17:30", "17:40", 
"17:50", "18:00", "18:10", "18:20", "18:30", "18:40", "18:50", 
"19:00", "19:10", "19:20", "19:30", "19:40", "19:50", "20:00", 
"20:10", "20:20", "20:30", "20:40", "20:50", "21:00", "21:10", 
"21:20", "21:30", "21:40", "21:50", "22:00", "22:10", "22:20", 
"22:30", "22:40", "22:50", "23:00", "23:10", "23:20", "23:30", 
"23:40", "23:50", "00:00", "00:10", "00:20", "00:30", "00:40", 
"00:50", "01:00", "01:10", "01:20", "01:30", "01:40", "01:50", 
"02:00", "02:10", "02:20", "02:30", "02:40", "02:50", "03:00", 
"03:10", "03:20", "03:30", "03:40", "03:50", "04:00", "04:10", 
"04:20", "04:30", "04:40", "04:50", "05:00", "05:10", "05:20", 
"05:30", "05:40", "05:50", "06:00", "06:10", "06:20", "06:30", 
"06:40", "06:50", "07:00", "07:10", "07:20", "07:30", "07:40", 
"07:50", "08:00", "08:10", "08:20", "08:30", "08:40", "08:50", 
"09:00", "09:10", "09:20", "09:30", "09:40", "09:50", "10:00", 
"10:10", "10:20", "10:30", "10:40", "10:50", "11:00", "11:10", 
"11:20", "11:30", "11:40", "11:50", "12:00", "12:10", "12:20", 
"12:30", "12:40", "12:50", "13:00", "13:10", "13:20", "13:30", 
"13:40", "13:50", "14:00", "14:10", "14:20", "14:30", "14:40", 
"14:50", "15:00", "15:10", "15:20", "15:30", "15:40", "15:50", 
"16:00", "16:10", "16:20", "16:30", "16:40", "16:50", "17:00", 
"17:10", "17:20", "17:30", "17:40", "17:50", "18:00", "18:10", 
"18:20", "18:30", "18:40", "18:50", "19:00", "19:10", "19:20", 
"19:30", "19:40", "19:50", "20:00", "20:10", "20:20", "20:30", 
"20:40", "20:50", "21:00", "21:10", "21:20", "21:30", "21:40", 
"21:50", "22:00", "22:10", "22:20", "22:30", "22:40", "22:50", 
"23:00", "23:10", "23:20", "23:30", "23:40", "23:50", "00:00", 
"00:10", "00:20", "00:30", "00:40", "00:50", "01:00", "01:10", 
"01:20", "01:30", "01:40", "01:50", "02:00", "02:10", "02:20", 
"02:30"), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L), .Label = c("Personal care", "Sleep", "Eating", "Other personal care", 
"Employment", "Main job", "Second job", "Activites related to employment", 
"Study", "School or University", "Free time study", "House and family care", 
"Food management", "Household maintenance", "Making care for textiles", 
"Gardening and pet care", "Construction and repairs", "Shopping and services", 
"Household management", "Childcare of own household member", 
"Help to an adult household member", "Volunteer work and meeting", 
"Organisational work", "Informal help to others", "Participatory activties", 
"Social care", "Social life", "Entertainment and culture", "Resting", 
"Sport and outdoor activities", "Physical exercise", "Productive exercise", 
"Sportsrelated activities", "Hobbies, games and computing", "Arts and hobbies", 
"Computing", "PC Games", "Mass media", "Reading", "Tv and video", 
"Radio and music", "Travel and unspecified time use", "Travel by purpose", 
"Punctuating activity"), class = "factor"), value = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 252, 252, 250, 246, 
246, 252, 242, 238, 236, 228, 228, 228, 218, 208, 200, 192, 186, 
178, 150, 144, 138, 126, 122, 108, 88, 76, 72, 68, 60, 54, 40, 
34, 30, 28, 28, 28, 14, 12, 10, 6, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 6, 6, 6, 
10, 10, 6, 6, 8, 4, 4, 2, 4, 6, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 6, 4, 8, 12, 18, 20, 52, 
64, 76, 106, 116, 124, 142, 158, 166, 174, 180, 186, 196, 204, 
218, 222, 222, 220, 230, 232, 234, 234, 236, 238, 240, 240, 240, 
238, 240, 240, 244, 246, 248, 248, 250, 248, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 
0, 6, 6, 15, 18, 9, 0, 0, 15, 6, 3, 6, 18, 21, 27, 36, 33, 30, 
18, 12, 18, 21, 27, 18, 24, 36, 27, 27, 18, 15, 27, 36, 24, 18, 
12, 15, 18, 18, 21, 18, 18, 12, 30, 39, 51, 42, 45, 45, 72, 78, 
69, 63, 66, 54, 36, 27, 36, 27, 27, 27, 12, 12, 12, 12, 21, 15, 
18, 21, 27, 24, 27, 24, 27, 24, 33, 39, 36, 36, 45, 54, 54, 60, 
54, 54, 42, 48, 51, 51, 45, 48, 45, 48, 54, 42, 42, 48, 45, 45, 
33, 39, 33, 36, 21, 18, 18, 18, 18, 12, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 
3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 16, 8, 0, 20, 12, 8, 8, 8, 12, 24, 48, 40, 28, 
32, 36, 40, 44, 44, 52, 28, 28, 44, 40, 40, 32, 28, 36, 36, 36, 
48, 44, 48, 32, 36, 28, 28, 36, 32, 24, 12, 12, 16, 8, 12, 4, 
16, 12, 12, 16, 0, 12, 16, 12, 8, 4, 12, 8, 4, 12, 8, 12, 12, 
4, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 12, 16, 12, 12, 16, 16, 16, 20, 28, 24, 
20, 32, 28, 28, 16, 20, 24, 48, 28, 16, 12, 20, 20, 12, 12, 8, 
4, 12, 4, 40, 36, 32, 20, 32, 40, 44, 60, 60, 28, 20, 24, 60, 
60, 48, 32, 32, 24, 28, 28, 12, 12, 8, 8, 12, 8, 4, 8, 4, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6, 6, 18, 
30, 30, 30, 36, 42, 42, 54, 54, 66, 66, 90, 102, 156, 168, 162, 
186, 204, 216, 234, 240, 246, 258, 258, 264, 264, 270, 270, 270, 
270, 270, 282, 276, 270, 258, 258, 252, 222, 222, 210, 210, 216, 
216, 198, 204, 216, 216, 210, 210, 252, 246, 240, 258, 258, 258, 
264, 270, 276, 264, 252, 258, 258, 258, 264, 264, 264, 258, 186, 
174, 168, 162, 144, 144, 120, 102, 108, 84, 78, 72, 48, 54, 48, 
54, 54, 60, 54, 54, 36, 36, 36, 42, 24, 24, 18, 12, 12, 6, 24, 
24, 24, 24, 30, 30, 30, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 1000L
), class = "data.frame")
```

My code:

```
melted_Activities<- melt(Activities)

plot<-ggplot(melted_Activities, aes(x = time,y = value,fill = variable)) + 
  geom_col(stats="bin")

plot + 
  labs(title = " Full-time workers who worked 1 to 4 days in a row during the week (N=128)", x="Time", y="Count", colour="Activties", fill="Activites")+
  theme(legend.position="right", axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0))+ 
  annotate("rect", fill = "black", alpha = 0.3, xmin = c(98), xmax = c(123), ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf) + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c( "04:00","05:00", "06:00", "07:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00","13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00", "18:00", "19:00", "20:00", "21:00","22:00", "23:00", "00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00"), expand = c(0,0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(-0,0))
```

Many thanks

The plot that I would like

[image]

The above figure was generated using this code:

```
melted_Activities<-melt(Activities)
melted_Activities %>% 
group_by(time, variable) %>% 
summarise(value = sum(value)) %>% 
ungroup %>% mutate(value = 100 * value/sum(value)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(time,value)) + 
  geom_col() +
labs(title = " Full-time workers who worked 1 to 4 days in a row during the week (N=128)", x="Time", y="Count", colour="Activties", fill="Activites")+theme(legend.position="right", axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0))+ annotate("rect", fill = "black", alpha = 0.3, xmin = c(98), xmax = c(123), ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf) + scale_x_discrete(breaks = c( "04:00","05:00", "06:00", "07:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00","13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00", "18:00", "19:00", "20:00", "21:00","22:00", "23:00", "00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00"), expand = c(0,0)) + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(-0,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Is that the `melted_Activities` in `dput`.  Also, the 'values' column is all 0

Comment: @akrun thanks for your time , yes

Comment: In your data, there is only a single frequency count.  May be `Activities %>% count(time) %>% mutate(n = n/sum(n))` and use that in `ggplot`

Comment: @akrun updated data, workin on your suggestion

Comment: @akrun Activities %>% 
count(time) %>% 
mutate(n = n/sum(n))%>% 

ggplot(Activities, aes(x = time,y = value,fill = variable)) + geom_col(stats="bin")
 I receive an error Mapping should be created with `aes() or `aes_()`.
>

Comment: Sorry, I saw your update, but I couldn't fully understand how you want to take the percentage.  Is it based on taking the sum of 'values' by 'variable' and 'time'

Comment: @akrun,  yes that is correct

Comment: May be `melted_Activities %>% group_by(time, variable)  %>% summarise(value = sum(value)) %>% ungroup %>% mutate(value = 100 * value/sum(value))`

Comment: @akrun many thanks I updated my question how can I improve the graph generated based on your code. So would like to see the activities as well percentages?

Comment: Take out the `ungroup` line and see if that helps. It's hard to tell though because you have all 0 for personal care. Maybe you can create a subset that has fewer times (just to keep things minimal) but includes more non-zero values of the categorical variable

Comment: @camille many thanks I reduced my data as well removed the ungroup line but still not working

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to split people doing different things (`value`) by time into groups and then divide each number in that group by the total number of people in that group.

```
d %>% group_by(time) %>% mutate(value = value/sum(value)) %>%
    ungroup() %>% mutate(time = lubridate::ymd_hm(paste0("2001-01-01", time))) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = time, y = value, colour = variable)) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_x_datetime(breaks = scales::date_breaks("2 hours"), date_labels = "%H:%M")
```

[image]

Comment: many thanks when you have time could you please explain to me how you did it

Comment: one more question 1 can be counted as a percentage 100%?

Comment: my question would be 0.25 is a percentage?

Comment: many thanks so the graph shows the precent of activities reported at different time steps?